# css nth-child not working (nth-of-type neither)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to set al the even titles from h2 in orange. I need to use nth-child.
I can't figure out what i did wrong...

```css
    *{
        font-size: 1em;  
    }
    h2{
       font-size: 1.5em
    }
    h2:first-letter{font-size: 150%}
    h2:nth-child(odd){
       color:#ef3909;
    }
```

The last line in css has the nth-child which does not work properly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set **nth-child(even)** to `<h2>` elements.

```css
.main article:nth-child(even) h2 {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
            <article>
               <a id="welkom"><h2>Welkom</h2></a>
               <p>
                  Dakwerken Jellen is al jaren de <strong>specialist in dakwerken</strong>. 
               </p>
            </article>
            
            <article>
               <a id="platteDaken"><h2>Platte daken</h2></a>
         
            </article>
            <article>
               <a id="gevelbekleding"><h2>Gevelbekleding</h2></a>
               <p>
                  Naast dakbedekking staan wij ook in voor de bekleding van gevels. U
               </p>
            </article>
            <article>
               <a id="zinkwerken"><h2>Zinkwerken</h2></a>
               <p>
                  Zink is reeds vele jaren een van de betere materialen om de regen via dakgoten te laten afvoeren. 
               </p>
            </article>
            <article>
               <a id="referenties"><h2>Referenties</h2></a>
               <p>
                 Een aantal referenties ...
               </p>
            </article>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but could you please tell me why the h2 should be after the nth-child, and why you use the main class for the nth-child?

i had something like this:h2:nth-child(odd){
   color:#ef3909;
}

Comment: If you count **nth-child** of `<h2>` directly it would be always 1 as it is included in `<article>` element.

Answer (score 1):

using `nth-child() is little bit confusing for new

here is the code for css

```
.main article:nth-child(2n) h2{
    color: orange;
}
```

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46xq6unr/)